# Sample integers except the ones in a specified set

Tags: python, random

Suppose I have a set of integers `exceptions = set([3, 2, 6, ...])`. What is the most efficient way to draw `num` samples of integers from the interval `[0,n)` uniformly at random except the ones that appear in `exceptions` using `python`.

Here are some ideas I've played with but are not satisfactory.

```
# Create a set of the integers I am interested in
integers = set(range(n)) - exceptions
# Draw samples from the set
samples = np.random.choice(integers, num)
```

In my case `n` is rather large (on the order of 10^12) such that creating the set seems like a waste of memory.

However, `len(exceptions)` is comparatively small (on the order of 10^6) such that rejection sampling might be a reasonable approach.

```
samples = []
# Iterate until we have enough samples
while len(samples) < num:
    # Draw a sample
    proposal = np.random.randint(n)
    # Accept or reject
    if proposal not in exceptions:
        samples.append(proposal)
```

Unfortunately, all the looping and set membership testing is rather slow. Obviously, I could write a `C`-extension or use `Cython` but I wanted to see whether you guys have a better idea.

*Edited to include suggestions in the comments.*

Comment: What type is `exceptions`? `proposal not in exceptions` will have different performance depending on what it is. Ex. membership testing is O(N) for lists and O(1) for sets, on average.

Comment: make  `exceptions` a set

Comment: I edited the question to include `exceptions` being a `set` yet the main question remains.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in case of exceptions being small compared to n, rejection might be your best shot; note that with `n=10**12` and `e=10**6` probability of getting invalid result is only one in a million, so you will be good without rejecting and re-randoming most of the time. If you need multiple samples anyway, it's probably a good idea to get much random numbers (like 101%) and then filter them all in bulk, discarding exceptions  (I believe there is a way in numpy to get multiple samples faster that in a loop). If there are still too many, simply truncate the result; if there are too little, generate more.

As the size of exceptions is getting bigger, you might try a different approach:

Assume you have a range of `n` integers and `e` exceptions. In fact, then, you are interested in getting one of `n-e` uniformly distributed results. So having `x = np.random.randint(n-e)` should be good enough, provided you can transform such a result into a meaningful one fast. First, an example to illustrate the idea:

- Let's assume n=100, set of exceptions = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 26, 27}
- case 1: your random result was 60. You have to count how many exceptions smaller than or equal to 60 are there: there are 13. So the result is 60+13=73.
- case 2: your random result was 22. There are 10 exceptions smaller than that, so you increase the result by 10, getting 32. There are however two more exceptions that are not greater than 32, but greater than 22, and therefore not yet counted. You have to further increase the value by 2, final result being 34.

The algorithm, then, would be as follows:

```
n = ...  # full range
exceptions = ...   # collection of your exceptions
e = len(exceptions)
def get_sample():
  x = np.random.randint(n-e)
  skipped = 0
  small_exceptions = count_small_exceptions(x, exceptions)
  while skipped < small_exceptions:
    skipped = small_exceptions
    small_exceptions = count_small_exceptions(x+skipped, exceptions)
  return x+skipped
```

In order to implement that, you need a fast way to count exceptions smaller than a given value - module [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) should do the trick, as it provides binary-search mechanisms on a sorted array.

Why does this work? The loop stops when `skipped == small_exceptions`, so there are exactly `skipped` exceptions in the range `0..(skipped+x)`. If the returned value (`skipped+x`) was an exception, the loop would have stopped earlier, because there would have been less exceptions in the previous iteration.

The exact cost analysis is not that easy, but if you assume that you have one exception for every `k` regular values, then increases in subsequent iterations are k times smaller each time. Worst-case scenario is when `exceptions=range(e)` and random `x` comes out as `0`. Then there would be `e` iterations, with small increase in every one of them. If `e` is small compared to `n` this shouldn't be a problem; otherwise, you might further improve this solution by storing exceptions as intervals instead, effectively merging all subsequent exceptions into only one 'hole' and one operation.